# Get NULL object excepction when saving only one sheet of Excel in mvc4

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

Given below is my code.. I have Excel template that contains 2 or three sheet. when I am performing and saving data on all excel its getting successful but if I am working on only one excel sheet it throws exception on xlPackage.Save();
HOW to save on only one sheet of Excel

```
String filePath = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IcxFileFormatPath"]);
filePath += @"\ARK_New_FromDeviceSettings.xlsx";
String Template = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IcxFileFormatTempPath"]);
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
FileInfo UITemplate = new FileInfo(Template + @"\ARK_New_FromDeviceSettings.xlsx");

using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile, UITemplate))
{             
    ExcelWorksheet systemWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["System Details"];

    if (systemWorksheet != null)
    {
        const int startRow = 2;
        int row = startRow;
        // DataTable dt
        foreach (var systemDetailList in systemDetail)
        {
            if (row > startRow)
                systemWorksheet.InsertRow(row);
            systemWorksheet.Cell(row, 1).Value = Convert.ToString(systemDetailList.ModbusTCPIDofDCUDevice);
            systemWorksheet.Cell(row, 2).Value = systemDetailList.DCUSerialNumber;
        }
   }
   xlPackage.Save();
}

// HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
Response.Clear();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=UIRateTemplate.xlsx");
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't do anything other than save the ExcelPackage if there is no "System Details" worksheet, why don't you move the line "xlPackage.Save()" one line up, before that close brace?  It will no longer save, but you aren't making any changes anyhow, and you'll eliminate the NullReferenceException.